# Can't get to treasure box items

Tags: tomodachi-life

You guys are the only I can depend on, so here goes nothing...

I've gotten many things like a tissue box, NES, and a basket ball. But when I go to the mii and select the Treasure Box, it only has "Special Foods." Can you tell me how to add the "Treasures" button? Or do they sit there never going to be used?

Comment: They appear in the pawn shop menu, so you can sell them. I'm not sure there's any way to give them to a Mii?

Comment: You should put that answer in the answers part so I can rate it.

Comment: Everyone gets an up rating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The treasures have no purpose other then to sell them at the [pawn shop](http://tomodachi.wikia.com/wiki/Pawn_Shop)

You can also give a treasure item to a Mii if you choose the "Give a present" option when a Mii wants to [confess](http://tomodachi.wikia.com/wiki/Confession) to another Mii.
Hope this helps!

Comment: You can sell it at the pawn shop but not sure you can give it to a Mii.

Answer (score 1):

They appear in the pawn shop, where you can sell them for cash.

I've heard there are special circumstances where you can give them to a Mii, but I can't confirm this personally.

Comment: Everyone said this so I'll press accept on this one. Plus, I've done this myself.

Comment: Same thing with the other answer

Answer (score 0):

> Treasures are special items that have special purposes, such as being just for the player to collect, sell, and or to gift to other Miis and trigger special events. Treasures can be obtained by playing games with the Miis and winning them as well as through viewing the Mii's dreams.
>
> There are two categories: Treasures and Special Foods. The treasures are most useful by being sold at the Pawn Shop. There is one option to give a treasure item to a Mii to ask another Mii out with, which can be amusing.

[Source](http://tomodachi.wikia.com/wiki/Treasures)

Comment: Please add something to your answer that's not a straight copy and paste from elsewhere.  We don't mind people pulling from outside sources, but we do expect you to do more than just that.